# Can I do a double move while moving silently and still avoid the −20 penalty?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, movement, stealth

Under move silent and hiding it says that you suffer a −20 check penalty, unless you move at half speed. What I'm wondering is, with a Move of 30, can I use my move action to move 15 (half speed), and then use my standard action as another move action to move another 15 — without triggering the −20 penalty? Essentially, can I still move 30 feet without a penalty to my hiding and move silently, if I give up my standard action?

Answer (score 21):

Yes, kinda.

This means that you are moving half speed during whatever action you use to move.  If you move one move action, you need to move half speed - in other words, every 5' of movement costs you 10' of movement.

If you have a 30' move, then yes, you can use two move actions while moving at half speed during each, moving 30' total in the round and not incurring the −5 (not −20) [Stealth penalty for speed](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/hide.htm).

Answer (score 4):

The other answer is correct, you can do this.

If you think about it though it is because you are giving up your action to do so. In normal movement you can give up your action to move 60' instead of 30'. When moving silently you can give up your action to move 30' rather than 15'.

You are still moving at half the speed you would otherwise.